# が function in this sentence?

Tags: particles

In this sentence 昨日レストランに行きましたがすごく美味しかったですよ, what is the function of が? So far I have learned that this particle is used to emphasize what comes before it or is used as "but". However, I cannot understand the particular usage in this sentence.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5010

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「昨日{きのう}レストランに行{い}きました**が**すごく美味{おい}しかったですよ。」

When 「が」 is used as a conjunction mid-sentence, it means "***and***" as often as it means "***but***".

Even [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%8C) gives you that usage.

> "I went to a restaurant yesterday ***and*** it was very yummy."

Comment: "even" jisho.org, lol...