# What does が mean in the following context

Tags: particle-が

In the following sentence

"私も髪を切りたいんですが、いい所を知っていますか。"

Does the が mean "but...(implied reason of not knowing a good place to get a haircut)" in a similar way to が at the end of a sentence would?

Comment: Also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72494/5010