# Asking questions using が?

Tags: questions

Can someone explain why が is used here to ask a question, instead of か? If it is to be more polite, can both be used interchangeably?

Situation: A man is ordering something at a burger shop.

Conversation:

> 男の人: すみません、スペシャルバーガーのセットをください。
>
> 店員: はい、ポテトかサラダがつきます***が***。
>
> 男の人: サラダをお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

This が is not a replacement of か. You cannot use か in the first place; ポテトかサラダがつきますか ("Does it come with either fries or salad?") doesn't make sense as a question from the clerk.

This が is the が which you probably remember as "but". In this sentence, が is there to provide background information, and the actual question (どちらにしますか, "Which do you like?") has been omitted.

- [けど usage in ”魔石灯”がいい例だけど、”魔石”は…](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5010)
- [が function in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72494/5010)
- [けれども as a neutral connector](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19155/5010)

> はい、ポテトかサラダがつきますが（、どちらにしますか）。
> Okay. It comes with fries or salad, so...(which do you like?)

In Japanese, it's common to omit the final part of a sentence if it can be inferred. If a sentence ends with "が?" or "けど?", something like "what do you say/think?" or "what does it matter?" is often the omitted question. Similar examples:

- 明日は日曜日ですが？
  But it's Sunday tomorrow, are you sure?
- はい、フランス語は話せますが？
  Yes, I can speak French, but why do you ask?

Comment: It's my first time on this website, and I must say I'm surprised at the the depth and the seriousness of your answer. Thank you so much! Your links help to clarify many doubts I had with が/げど　as well. Thank you!

Comment: @tzemina I know there are other sites if you want to get quick answers, but I like this site because the long and serious answers are properly appreciated by people (as well as search engines).