# How do I introduce something new and then describe it in the same sentence?

Tags: adjectives, english-to-japanese, conjunctions, conversational

I recently learned how to use これ, この, それ, その etc. but I was wondering how to introduce something new to someone, like これはゲームです and then adding onto that sentence to describe it (for example in English I could say “this is a game, it is new/fun/boring etc.”). I know I could use something like このゲームはおもしろいです but it seems like this implies the person I’m talking to already knows what a game is. Is there any way to introduce something new and describe it in the same sentence?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use が and けど. You may know their basic meaning is "but", but they can also be used to give introductory/background information before diving into your main point.

- これはゲームですが、おもしろいですよ。
  これはゲームですけど、おもしろいですよ。
  This is a game, and it's fun.
- 明日【あした】は日曜日【にちようび】ですが、どこに行きたい【いきたい】ですか？
  明日は日曜日ですけど、どこにいきたいですか？
  It's Sunday tomorrow, so where do you want to go?

Related: [けど usage in ”魔石灯”がいい例だけど、”魔石”は…](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5010)