# meaning of だけど in this context

Tags: grammar, anime

recently I started watching samurai champloo & someone asked mugen for his name.

he answered: ムゲンだけど

I was wondering what the role of だけど in this context was. I thought maybe it's the same as adding "..." after mugen in English.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/%e3%81%91%e3%81%a9-usage-in-%e9%ad%94%e7%9f%b3%e7%81%af-%e3%81%8c%e3%81%84%e3%81%84%e4%be%8b%e3%81%a0%e3%81%91%e3%81%a9-%e9%ad%94%e7%9f%b3-%e3%81%af)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your intuition is pretty accurate.
It's expressing a feeling of "...what does that have to do with anything?" or "why are you asking?". Mugen doesn't understand why he's being asked his name.

A similar pattern would be:

A:「何才ですか？」

B:「30才だけど...」

A: How old are you?

B: I'm 30... (what does that have to do with anything?)

Or:

A:「だれの車？」

B:「俺のだけど...」

A: Whose car is this?

B: It's mine... (why are you asking?)

Comment: thanks alot, you explained it really well 